# Returning to previous (root) ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

I have a list of products in a TableView. With a tap on a product, I open UIPageViewController which holds simmilar products and user is able to swipe between them. What I need to make is that when user is on first item and if he swipes back, UIPageViewController must dissapear and user should be back on TableView. Default swipe gesture is enabled (when you swipe from edge to go back but it doesn't suit my need). The principle should be the same, just without requirement to swipe from the edge but it should work as a regulr swipe. Could you guys help with any ideas?

Comment: Are you using navigation controller? you can swipe anywhere in the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a "back" button with a swipe.
So, you need to add the swipe gesture recogniser, and then dismiss the view.

In the viewDidLoad()

```
var swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipes:"))
swipe.direction = .Right
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

And in the handler function.

```
func swipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
 if (sender.direction == .Right) {
     self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true); //If you are now using navigation controller, just change to the apropriate function to "go back"
}
}
```

Comment: Back swipe is already functioning in app but you have to drag from the edge. What I would like to achieve is go back to list with a simple swipe when on first view controller in uipageviewcontroller. I could implement your answer and also check if i am on first viewcontroller, that would probably work. But is there any "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Its exactly what this code does... swipe ANYWHERE in the screen (Left to right movement) and it will call the function, the function will go back to the preview screen.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

> self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true);